# TFS 2015 permissions required to create new project?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I have two users say user Ad and user Us, Ad has admin rights and is the account used to install and configure TFS 2015, user Us is an admin which has all permissions needed for an administrator.

Now when I tried to create a new project from Visual Studio 2015 the get the below error:
Error 
The Project Creation Wizard encountered an error while creating reports to the SQL Server Reporting Services on

Interestingly, my Ad account does not have SYSDBA permission on the databases when i get the error. But if i provide the SYSDBA permission to the Ad account the project creation utility works.

I want to know how is this possible? and is there a way to create a new project in TFS 2015 without having the SYSDBA permission?

Help appriciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just create a new project, usually you only need to be the memeber of  the **Project Collection Administrators Group** and have the **Create new projects permission** set to **Allow**.

However, if you have S*QL Server Analysis Services* and *SQL Server Reporting Services* been configured for the deployment or  a *SharePoint Web application* been configured for your deployment,  you also need to become a member of [Team Foundation Content Managers group](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/grant-permissions-to-reports) and **get Full Control permissions** on the server that **hosts SharePoint Products**.

> **Has SQL Server Analysis Services and SQL Server Reporting Services been configured for the deployment?**
>
> If so, ask your administrator to add you as a member of the [Team
>   Foundation Content Managers group](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/report/admin/grant-permissions-to-reports) on the server that hosts SQL Server
>   Reporting Services. **Without these permissions**, you’ll be **unable** to
>   create a team project.

More detail info please refer the link from MSDN: **[Create a team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/create-team-project)**

Comment: Thanks for the info, surprisingly i have all the above mentioned permissions, and i can create a new project only when the service account Ad has SQLDBA permission. Is this a must required access?

Comment: Usually not. You just need to have the permissions above mentioned.  Did the account is used reporting by TFS? If so, you may need the  `TfsWarehouseDataReader` , please see this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2013/01/24/permissions-needed-for-tfs-service-account-in-sql-for-tfs-2012/). Also take a look at [Database Permissions Required to Configure TFS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2010/08/20/database-permissions-required-to-configure-tfs/)

Comment: Did this happen to all of your account and machines when created a team project and creating reports need the SYSDBA permission?

Comment: I will give a try with the TfsWarehouseDataReader permission. Yes we have reporting and analysis configured for the new projects. Not all the account needs the SQLDBA permission as for example Us does not need and it is used to create the project, but only the Ad account needs to have.

Comment: providing TfsWareHouseDataReader permission did not help. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/add-administrator-tfs check the question answer section and What are the optimal permissions needed to administer TFS across all its components and dependencies? question it says sysadmin is required.

Comment: I'm afraid this is cause user AD is the account used to install and configure TFS. So need to have the sysadmin or the db_owner group membership for the configuration database, the reporting and analysis databases, and the databases for team project collections. Go back to your original question, you don't have to  create a new project in TFS 2015 with having the SYSDBA permission.  Your test also proved this point (Us can create a new project successfully).

Comment: yeah so my Us account does not need to have any other permission, but my question is why does the Ad account needs the SYSDBA access. We currently have Ad account the db_owner permission, but that is not sufficient it seems. And how does the Ad account not having a SYSDBA permission effect my Us account to create a new project. 
Your help appreciated.

Comment: Most likely is creating team project do not need to have a SYSDBA permission for every account. However, the permission are needed related to the connection between TFS and SQL Server Reporting Services .Without the permission TFS can't creating reports or interactive with the SQL Server Reporting Services.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the help. I guess the Ad account should be having SYSDBA permission as per MS.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions for TFS Team project creation:
 1. Add the user to TFS Admin console users or to Project collection Admin group
 2. If sharepoint is available, Add user to sharepoint Farm admin and also site collection administrators
 3. If Reporting is configured, Give user Team Foundation Content Manager role.
Still if team project creation fails then **Depending on the error** check if user is added to TfsReports Folder security and then in to specific collection level folder security.
 4. If error is related to Datasources then check if user is available at both reportDS and OlapreportDS security.

If you can give the exact error message base on that recommendations can be made. The above information is the basic requirement.